# Struck in cheerfulness

Tags: meaning

> *Szósz was inescapably struck in cheerfulness but went up a jubilation or two when he saw a young Fischer.*

This is just one sentence from the novel by Tibor Fischer, *Under the Frog*. The official translation of this clause to my native language can be translated back to English, word by word, as follows:

> *Szósz was the embodimemnt of the warm-hearted man and every time he saw a young Fisher he exploded, even two times, with enthusiasm*.

(I translated exactly word by word the official translation.)

Do you think that the translation of the sentence is in terms of the meaning OK?

Comment: It is really **struck** and not **stuck**? It could be a typo, IMHO.

Comment: In my source it is struck.

Comment: I guess it's a typo. Look at [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inescapably+stuck%2C+inescapably+struck&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinescapably%20stuck%3B%2Cc0). This Szosz was "stuck" in (a?) "cheerful mode". The guy was always cheerful.

Comment: I think *struck* refers to the "mold" from which Szósz was created.

Comment: "Jubilation" is wittily used as an incremental unit of measure.  compare:  *turned the volume up a notch or two". The translation misses the metaphorical language entirely.

Comment: A commemorative medal can be "struck in silver". Szósz was struck in cheerfulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with this translation, assuming you've stated it correctly.

First of all, "cheerful" is different than "warm-hearted". Cheerful means outwardly, visibly happy and positive, while warm-hearted has more to do with the way you feel about and treat people. You can be one without the other.

Secondly, "went up a jubilation or two" simply means an increase in cheerfulness; I think "exploded" is far too strong a word here.

Finally, increasing "a jubilation or two" is like increasing or going up in cheerfulness by a couple of levels, not twice or "two times".

But the original sentence is certainly unusual -- it is literary or poetic, and not straightfoward, thus difficult to translate well.